# Is it possible to have use vanilla CSS files in Magento 2 via a child theme?

Tags: css, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I understand that it's built to compile .less files, but I'd really like to be able add vanilla CSS files in a nice way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely possible. The less files just get compiled into css in the pub directory. To add your own static css files you will just put them in your css directory (/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/web/css) and they will be accessed just like any less compiled css file.

Depending on your magento configuration you may need to first run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from your magento installation's root directory.

Comment: Should I be putting them in `/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/web/css` or `/pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css`?

Comment: You would put them in `/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/web/css`. You should never edit anything directly in pub/static as those files get overwritten by magento automatically. If you create your css file in your theme directory then paste a link to it like this in your browser `http://m2.dev/pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css/file.css` you will see your file in your browser and at that location in the file system. Depending on your magento configuration you may need to first run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from your magento installation's root directory.

Comment: That worked, it was the terminal command that I was missing! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, there is a magento stack exchange network for questions like this. I would recommend using that network instead of stack overflow for magento questions. magento.stackexchange.com